# MySQL multiple joins on the same table selects only 1 row in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

Table "posts" contains articles and 3 last userIDs (us1, us2, us3) of people who posted comments to each article. I need to join "usertable" to get names of last comment posters. This is my query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT m.id, m.comment, m.us1, m.us2, m.us3,p.name,o.name,t.name,
FROM posts m 
LEFT JOIN usertable p ON m.us1=u.id
LEFT JOIN usertable o ON m.us2=u.id
LEFT JOIN usertable t ON m.us3=u.id   

where m.lid = '$pid' order by m.id desc limit 0,20")  or die('Error');

while(list($id, $comment, $us1, $us2, $us3, $name1, $name2, $name3) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
echo "$id<br />";
}
```

Unfortunately, the "echo"of this result is:

```
79
79
79
79
79...
```

"79" is the ID of last row in "posts" table. So, why the result of this query is only one row selected from "posts"?

Comment: What is this table alias "u" (m.us1=u.id, m.us2=u.id, m.us3=u.id)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with your SQL referencing "u.id" when there is no table "U" in this picture. Try:

```
SELECT m.id, m.comment, m.us1, m.us2, m.us3, p.name, o.name, t.name
FROM posts m 
LEFT JOIN usertable p ON m.us1=p.id
LEFT JOIN usertable o ON m.us2=o.id
LEFT JOIN usertable t ON m.us3=t.id
```

Also, switch to mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_ since the mysql extension is deprecated and soon to be removed. It's also worth taking a look at PDO. Check both of those out over at php.net.

Comment: Nah, you've probably just been staring at it for too long. That's what stack exchange is around for, a fresh set of eyes.